# Assembly, PDP11, using ascii code to jump to specific label

Tags: assembly, branch, subroutine, pdp-11

I have a small question:
I have a subroutine that receives a letter (let's say `"A"`) from the stack, and I want to jump to a label with the same name.

For example:

```
main: mov -(sp), r1
  br r1
A: mov r0,@#tpb
```

`r1` will hold the value `"A"` which he got from the stack.
then I want it to branch into label `"A"`.

Thanks.

Comment: Prepare a look-up table which contains offsets of all the labels `A`..`Z`?

Comment: Would -push [A]  -ret   work? kinda thing

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll have to make sure `A` is an exported symbol.  Then, figure out how to look up the symbol table from your executable, search for the matching entry in the table, and then jump to the provided address.  Wikipedia says that the PDP11 uses the [a.out executable file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out).